# Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): key of size 10 not supported by this algorithm. only key of size 16, 24 or 32 supported

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to encrypt a password using `mcrypt_encrypt()`. It is working fine on `localhost`, but when goes to online, my output is `""` and I'm getting this warning:

> **Warning**:  mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 10 not supported by
>   this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported

This is the code I'm using:

```
$text="thisismypassword123";
$salt="1234567824";
return trim (
    base64_encode (
        mcrypt_encrypt (
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv (
                mcrypt_get_iv_size (
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ),
                MCRYPT_RAND
            )
        )
    )
);
```

What could be the cause of this and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please do not use MCRYPT_MODE_ECB mode as the salt will not be used. use MCRYPT_MODE_CBC. It is more reliable to use  the 'openssl_' encryption routines rather than `mcrypt`.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 5):

Simple way to solve backward compatibilities is to fill the current password with \0.

For instance, for your current $key = "1234567890" on PHP 5.4, as the current key size is 10, it will stop working on PHP 5.6 version.

To solve it without any impact on application just change to $key = "1234567890\0\0\0\0\0\0" (until reaches **16** or **32**,...)

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to encrypt a password

[This is probably a mistake](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016). The fact that you're calling the key a "salt" makes me even more wary. Need to store users' passwords? *Encryption* is **NOT** the right tool for the job. *Password hashing* is. [They're wildly different concepts](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

But let's ignore the "wrong tool for the job" aspect and assume you were encrypting non-password strings for some reason. Even in this scenario, your encryption code is insecure.

> ```
> return trim ( // Why are you trimming this?
>     base64_encode (
>         mcrypt_encrypt (
>             MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, // Not AES
>             $salt,
>             $text,
>             MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,     // The WORST mode possible
>             mcrypt_create_iv (   // ECB mode doesn't use an IV
>                 mcrypt_get_iv_size (
>                     MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
>                 ),
>                 MCRYPT_RAND      // Even if an IV was used, MCRYPT_RAND
>                                  // is a bad choice! Use MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
>             )
>         )
>     )
> );
> ```

Even if you fixed the issues above, you have a more serious issue: [Chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).

Solution:

- For passwords, use [the password hashing API](https://secure.php.net/password_hash)
- For general-purpose data encryption, use [a cryptography library that offers authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

Can you please tell whomever gave you the code snippet that they're spreading insecure code around the internet? Thanks.

Comment: Just to shed some light on why this is so insecure.  I have some legacy code that is very similar to this and the reason is because of an old version of MySQL using the AES_ENCRYPT function.  This code is how you replicate MySQLs encryption in PHP.

Comment: If you need it for a "migrate to secure encryption" project, then that's fine. Don't rely on it. You can completely drop the `mcrypt_create_iv()` function call and speed things up.

Answer (score 3):

What is unclear about the warning? Provide a key of an acceptable size.

The key is what you have called $salt, it is not a salt, it is the encryption key. Rename it to make the code more clear.

Some instances may add padding bytes to the key but that is non-standard and may be different for different implementations. Do not trust parameter padding, specify the full length.

Also from th encrypt docs:

> MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES-256, it's a different variant of the Rijndael block cipher. If you want AES-256 in mcrypt, you have to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with a 32-byte key.

You should be using the AES options.

The code uses ECB mode which is not secure, should not be used and does not use a IV. Probably what you want to do is use CBC mode which does require an IV. The same IV will be needed for decryption.

There should be no need to `trim` Base64 encoding.

Lastly, nesting several levels of functions (6 here) may seem like a good idea but it makes debugging almost impossible since intermediate results can not be inspected.

Then there is `mcrypt`, it is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.6 and higher, your `$salt` needs to be a random string that is **either 16, 24 or 32 characters long**. Your localhost probably still uses an older version of PHP.

This code should work both on localhost and on your server :

```
$text="thisismypassword123";
$salt="ddv21sd5dv56sd51"; // <- 16 characters long
return trim (
    base64_encode (
        mcrypt_encrypt (
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv (
                mcrypt_get_iv_size (
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ),
                MCRYPT_RAND
            )
        )
    )
);
```

---

## Note

Even though this code does *work*, there are still other issues with it you may want to consider.

See the other answers (most in particular [**Scott Arciszewski**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224584/scott-arciszewski)'s answer) for details on what else is wrong with your code and why **you shouldn't even be using `mcrypt_encrypt()` in the first place!**

Comment: Please do not use `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` mode as the salt will not be used.

Comment: @RyanVincent : What would you recommend as an alternative to `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`?

Comment: @RyanVincent : So what are you saying? What alternative do YOU suggest for `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`?

Comment: Sorry, 1) don't use `mcrypt`. 2) If you do then use: MCRYPT_MODE_CBC. 3) I suggest using the `openssl_` symmetric functions instead of `mcrypt`.  maybe interesting:  : http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of

Comment: If you want a library then: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption is more than adequate but requires PHP 5.4 or later.

Comment: @RyanVincent Note `$salt` is the key, the OP misnamed the key. The IV is `mcrypt_create_iv (
                mcrypt_get_iv_size (
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ),
                MCRYPT_RAND
            )` which as you state is not used and is inappropriate for ECB mode.

Comment: @zaph, Thanks for the clarification. I really wanted to say "please don't use "mcrypt'". ;-/

Comment: @RyanVincent : I just added a "please don't use `mcrypt_encrypt()` note / disclaimer at the bottom of my answer.